# Run php script in command in symfony

Tags: php, shell, symfony, cmd, command

I want to run php script in command line. I have created this file into root folder. and want to run only once.

binary.php

```
global $em;
$binaryContentRepository = $em->getRepository('\xxx\Entity\xxxx');
$datas = $binaryContentRepository->getAllAttechment();
foreach($datas as $data){
    $ext =  pathinfo($data['filename'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    file_put_contents("C:\\xxxxxx\\".$data['id'].".".$ext, $data['content']);
}
```

I have try to run this file `php -f binary.php`. But can not run successfully.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes. Fatal error: Call to a member function getRepository() on null

Comment: where is `$em;` set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Symfony is the command line you need to create a Symfony command.

Note: just like a controller in a command you must have your dependency injection setup if you want to communicate to a database with entity manager.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Then you would execute from the Symfony project root:

php bin/console your_command_name